# Get height of paragraph that includes text and image

Tags: html, css, string, html-lists, adobe-edge

Im trying to get the height of a text element that has images in it.

The paragraph with text and two images:

```
<p id="txth">
    <ul>
        <li id="snow">
            <span class="title">Snow</span>
        </li>
        Hello
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li id="rain">
            <span class="title">Rain</span>
        </li>
        Hello
    </ul>
</p>
```

The CSS:

```
.title {
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-left: 7px;
}

#snow {
  list-style-image:url("images/snow.png");      
}

#rain {
  list-style-image:url("images/rain.png");      
}
```

To get the height:

```
textHeight = sym.$("#txth").height();
```

This works if I'm not using lists, but I don't know how to write this without using a list. What can I do to get the height of this paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `<p>` tag rather use a `<div>`, as `<ul>` and `<li>` tags seem to always cause problems when it comes to their display properties (`display:block` or `inline`) when placed inside `<p>` tags.

```
<div id="txth">
  <ul>
    <li id="snow">
      <span class="title">Snow</span>
    </li>
    Hello
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li id="rain">
      <span class="title">Rain</span>
    </li>
    Hello
  </ul>
</div>
```

Im not sure about the `sym` before the selector but this should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var textHeight = $("#txth").css("height");
    alert(textHeight);

});
```

Comment: Thanks, Wandile, your answer was my conclusion as well - I found out right after I posted the question, but figured there was no need to delete it since others might run into the same problem. The "sym" is Adobe Edge Animate, so your answer will be easier for others to understand than mine I guess :-)

Comment: No sweat buddy, I have ran into this problem before when using Wordpress custom templates content was being inserted as ul li inside p tags had to correct this to carry on, if my answer is relevent to your solution then just accept it for closure :-), thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't able to use element <ul> in <p>, so it's not work in your code.

User Either span or div or article instead of using p.